# How can I store Google Maps API keys not using app.json?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, expo, api-key

I have to store my Google Maps API Key in a safe way (not a commited file), but as i'm using Expo, the Google Maps API key is stored in `app.json` file, as the following example:

```
    "ios": {
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is, as my `app.json` file should be commited, where should I store those keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store them in a `.env` file like this `GOOGLE_API_KEY=yourKey`.
Then import to to files as needed with react-native-dotenv package;
`import { GOOGLE_API_KEY } from 'react-native-dotenv'`
The `.env` file is also never committed to Github.

Also, a good idea to check the AndroidManifest.xml file to make sure the key has not been exposed there.

Comment: Storing the keys in a .env file, i won't be able to access them in ```app.json``` Expo file, as it's a .json. The question is, what approach should I take to store the keys in app.json.

Comment: @Marcelo Wippel, this should work for Expo too.
Please check out this post; start at third post from top.

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/83

Comment: I'm trying to see how to use this for the actual map as originally asked. This answer makes it clear how to import the env var into app, but I don't see a way to pass the imported value to the `MapView` component?

Comment: how can you import it from a json file?